# Proof that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n/3^n$ has the Cantor distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cantor-set

[Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution) is the probability distribution whose cumulative distribution function is the Cantor function, according to Wikipedia.

In this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115907/can-you-simulate-from-a-cantor-distribution), the answer says that the distribution of

$\displaystyle Z= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{A_n}{3^n}\tag*{}$

where $A_n = 0,2$ with equal probability is the Cantor distribution.

How do I prove that? That is, how can I prove that the CDF of $Z$ is the Cantor function?

**My research:**

By using the Corollary 4.3(p.9) in [this paper](https://aimath.org/%7Emorrison/Research/RandomWalks.pdf) I can calculate the CDF of $Z-1/2(=S)$ by

$\displaystyle F(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{xt}}{t} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos{\frac{t}{3^n}}dt\tag*{}$

So I think I have to prove that this is a translation of the Cantor function, but I couldn't prove that.

Comment: Can you do this first step?  The distribution of $Z$ has value $1/2$ on the interval $(1/3,2/3)$.

Comment: @GEdgar For $z\in (1/3,2/3)$, $P(Z\leq z)$ is equal to $P(Z \leq 1/3)$, since if $1/3<Z\leq z$ we need to have $A_1 = 2$ and that means $ Z>2/3$, which is contradiction. So we need to calculate $P(Z\leq 1/3)$, and that equals $P(A_1=0)$ which is $1/2$. Is this correct?

Comment: The next step:  the distribution of $Z$ has value $1/4$ on$(1/9,2/9)$ and has value $3/4$ on $(7/9,8/9)$.

Comment: @GEdgar If $z\in (1/9,2/9)$ then similarly $P(Z\leq z)=P(Z\leq 1/9)=P(A_1=0,A_2=0)=1/4$, and if $z\in (7/9, 8/9)$, we have $P(Z\leq z) = P(Z < 2/3) + P(2/3 \leq Z\leq z) =P(A_1=0)+P(A_1=1, A_2=0)=1/2+1/4=3/4$. I see how it goes, but not sure about how we generalize. Maybe induction?

Comment: @GEdgar What’s the next step? If we continue what we did, I think we will have that the distribution of $Z$ is equal to the Cantor function, except on the Cantor set. How can we deal with the Cantor set?